# On pressing enter, the query should update the database using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.OnKey "{ENTER}", "dataconfigupdate"

End Sub
```

The above code works fine on one go, however, if I close the sheet and re-open it the above macro simply does not run. On Pressing Enter inside the excel sheet the row is not updated after the sheet is re-opened.

I had the below solution in mind, need a peer review on it.

```
   Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    if (Application.OnKey "{ENTER}")
    call dataconfigupdate

    End Sub
```

Comment: in what this post is different from [this other post of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086665/update-on-pressing-enter-or-changing-of-values-in-cell-using-vba)?

Comment: Yes it is quite different

Comment: Sendkeys isnt for that purpose.  Is this being called from a sheet?

Comment: @Win_umra, to me it is not. Let's hope they're not going to close it

Comment: No, the Sendkeys should be used on a specific sheet "EnterConfig". The values are fetched from database, saved in EnterConfig worksheet. Then user updates one of the entries like name or place, once he presses enter and immediately on press of enter the database should be updated with a pop-up message to the user. Worksheet_Change() event of the sheet I can think of but looking for a better solution.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this issue ? @HTH

Comment: I'm telling that one of SO rules is not to duplicate questions. If your previous one didn't get sufficient help it could be you should enhance it

Comment: @HTH I have edited and updated my question

Comment: I'm not making myself understood. But that must be me

Comment: Press <ENTER> on what? An Excel sheet? A specific cell on a sheet? A userform? Why on <ENTER> and not via Button?

Comment: Yes similar to on press of a button, the entire code of updating the database should execute on press of ENTER key?

Comment: In Excel? There is `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` which can be triggered by pressing ENTER. (Actually triggered by moving to another cell) - you can then check it is one of the correct cells using the `Target` variable.

Comment: "works sometimes" doesn't tell us or you anything. You need to work out the cases where it does or doesn't work. No one can solve "this works sometimes"

Comment: I have edited the code and scenario where the code is failing. As well as a proposed solution for a peer review.

Comment: can anyone look into the issue